# Should overtime be attributed to the day the shift started in case of a nightshift?

Tags: work-time, overtime

I want users to be able to register their actual hours of work and calculate from the difference to their due hours of work their overtime. For a day job this is just straight forward.

If somebody were to be working late into the night past midnight, I would attribute these hours to the last day shift.

However, some people might be working nightshifts, that regularly start at, say, 10:00 PM. In this case overtime would likely be accumulated on the next day. Would it still make sense to attribute the overtime to the day the work started?

Also, people will need to specify their due hours of work for me to be able to calculate their overtime. For a day job this means to specify their due hours of work for each weekday. For a night job however, would it feel natural for people to specify their due hours of work to the day the shift starts, or would that be confusing? If so, how can I support night jobs better?

---

**EDIT**:

I forgot to mention one important detail: people will not just be able to see their grand total overtime, but will also be able to print a sheet detailing their overtime for each day individually. This is why I need to attribute overtime to a date.

---

**EDIT:**

I just learned that the word **overtime** does not have as clear a meaning as I thought. For the purpose of this question I will therefore define overtime to be:

```
overtime = actual_hours_of_work - due_hours_of_work
```

with `actual_hours_of_work`: the time one actually spend working and `due_hours_of_work`: the contractually agreed hours of work.

---

**EDIT:**

There seems to be a misunderstanding that I'm about to calculate pay for overtime. I'm sure that's a very complicated matter and varies widely on company and jurisdiction and a fit all approach is doomed to fail. Not being a native english speaker it was maybe an error on my part to insist that overtime must be measured in units of time, since overtime contains the substring time.

Now it seems to me that the word overtime is not so much about time, but about pay for overtime. But this is not what I'm doing. I really just want to add up units of time. It did not even occur to me that overtime would be solely interpreted as pay for overtime.

So why do I want to add up overtime simply as units of time? In Germany it is customary to add up overtime to, say, 8 hours and then take a day off. Many people prefer that to being paid for overtime. Assuming that many contributers here are from the USA or Canada, is this not done in your countries?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136877/discussion-on-question-by-user1785730-should-overtime-be-attributed-to-the-day-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the general balance of opinion is that, if there is a need (or desire) to attribute the working hours of a shift to a single calendar day, then as a starting point you should treat the hours as falling into the calendar day when the shift started.

You may however have specific reasons to vary from this.

Also, it shouldn't be assumed that this principle would apply to payroll calculations.

A payroll calendar will be defined by a company to apply to a specific group of workers, and there is no general standard that can be assumed.

Answer (score 2):

> For a night job however, would it feel natural for people to specify their due hours of work to the day the shift starts, or would that be confusing?

Forget about "day" and "night" jobs, concentrate on shifts.  The employee will presumably be required to work X hours during their shift regardless of what time in the day ( or night ) that the shift starts.

Any hours worked over the X amount during their shift is their overtime.  Whether the shift started at 10 AM or 10 PM, just attribute the hours to the date that the shift started.

Comment: I've updated my question why I need to attribute overtime to dates.

Comment: @user1785730 That doesn't change my answer, the simplest solution would still be to use the date during which the shift started.

Answer (score 1):

From how I understand this your aim is to provide a tool for people to use to track their contracted and overtime hours - the problem is there's no single "correct" answer to this - how overtime hours are attributed potentially depends on many factors. Company policies, local laws, union agreements, the workers individual employment contract and work pattern.

I've worked in organisations that have literally *hundreds* of different work patterns - many of which calculate things like "overtime" very, very differently. And those that work patterns involving overnight work can be the most complicated, dare I say arcane.

So while

> For the purpose of this question I will therefore define overtime to be:
>
> overtime = actual_hours_of_work - due_hours_of_work
>
> with actual_hours_of_work: the time one actually spend working and due_hours_of_work: the contractually agreed hours of work.

*sounds* nice and simple - it's actually far too simplistic to be useful, at all.

So if you want to calculate overtime for someone you need to know how overtime hours are calculated for that person, in that job, at that company and in that locale. Anything else is going to be a pretty rough approximation at best.

Comment: I must say that I'm surprised that it's not that easy. For me it always has been. Could you please give me a concrete, real world example to illustrate this?

Comment: @user1785730, anyone who has experience of payroll or time-tracking systems knows that this area is an enormously complicated one. The method by which attendance is assessed or pay is calculated is typically subject to bargaining between management and the workforce, sometimes over many decades, and simplicity is not the goal of either side in that bargaining.

Answer (score 0):

This is bordering on silly.  In the United States, Canada, and likely other countries, the word "overtime" has a clear definition in both federal and state/provincial laws.  You don't get to magically redefine what it means or how it's calculated.  The calculation can actually vary with each state or province, and it's inscribed into law so that every business is working by the same set of rules.

I suggest you go back to whoever assigned you this work you're doing and clarify the goal you're trying to achieve, but first you should research the actual overtime law for your location, and walk into the meeting more informed.

Comment: Could you please provide an example for the calculation of overtime that would illustrate to me why my formula is 'bordering on silly'?

Comment: Example for British Columbia, Canada:  https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/employment-business/employment-standards-advice/employment-standards/hours/overtime-pay

Comment: Example for Saskatchewan, Canada.  Same country, different rules.  https://www.saskatchewan.ca/business/employment-standards/overtime/general-overtime-information/overtime-in-a-day-versus-overtime-in-a-week

Comment: Example for California.  https://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/faq_overtime.htm#:~:text=Yes%2C%20California%20law%20requires%20that,seventh%20consecutive%20day%20of%20work

Comment: All your examples deal with pay for overtime. This is not what I'm about. I clarified that in my question.

Comment: Am I the only one to find this answer very ironic? Someone asks how overtime is calculated and gets told "you know nothing, it's time you researched how overtime is calculated in your juristiction". Isn't that the very question they asked?